# What does "Someone call the burn unit" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes

[image: Someone call the burn unit]

Just saw this post on Imgur and I am not sure about the title.
Does that mean that the person has seen something that is really a sore to the eye
so he is asking others to call the burn unit to come and rescue him? I couldn't find a better context for this phrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One slang meaning of "burn", particularly in American English, is "insult (someone) in a particularly cutting way."  This can be used as either a verb or a noun.  For example, if Fred insults Jack in a particular witty or brutal fashion, a third party might exclaim "Damn Fred, you really burned him!" (verb) or alternatively "that was a savage burn!" (noun)

In this case, the tweet is calling Selena's music trash (insult), and the author of the imgur caption is describing this insult as a burn, considering it especially sharp or cutting (I'm not sure I would agree, but that is beside the point).  The person who has (rhetorically) been burnt here is Selena; the person who burnt her is the twitter poster; the imgur captioner is (humourously, metaphorically) calling the burn unit on Selena's behalf.

The burn(s) unit is a specialist department in a hospital, dealing with (actual!) burns, who would not typically respond to on-site emergencies.

Comment: What insult? Selena is hot, she's burning the viewers with her hotness...

Comment: Good answer, but it might be helpful to explain "calling the burn unit on Selena's behalf." As we can see, the original poster doesn't quite understand the meaning of *burn unit* (which cannot "come and rescue" anyone, since it's a hospital ward, not a team of doctors, or EMTs, or anyone who could "come" anywhere).

Comment: Thanks, Steve, for the detailed explanation!! Now I can understand why the show our ESL teacher showed us in class is called Comedy Central Roast.

Comment: And thanks @Juhasz for pointing "the burn unit" out, I just learned the expression " call the ambulance" so just figured the burn unit would show up and offer on-site treatment as well. :-p

Comment: @Juhasz - have done.

Comment: @cupofJoJo - yes, "roast" is related slang.  It is effectively a sustained version of burn.  Like a burn is a one off insult, a (comedy) roast is a series of insults.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu   The "burn" is mean enough, guess I wouldn't last a second if I were on the show!! Thanks Steve, you saved my day!! :-)

Comment: In Britain, and, I think the Brit part of the Anglosphere, we call it the **burns unit**.

Comment: "insult (someone) in a particularly cutting way." Explaining a metaphor in terms of another metaphor. Hmm.

Comment: The "author" looks wasted to me so I doubt one can impute much of anything to her. It would be nice to have the **original link**.

Comment: +1 for pointing out how many people are involved! 1. Selena Gomez, 2. KelseyHilson (the Tweeter), 3. ZWhiteZ33 (the Imgurer).

Answer (score -3):

It means the lady in the picture is hot (sexy).

The viewer has been "burned" by her hotness and needs emergency help from the burn unit.

The burn unit is referring to a unit in a hospital that treats burns.

This is a JOKE. :)

Comment: It's a joke, but not the one you think. @stevekeiretsu above has it right. The singer has been "burned" (i.e., insulted) by having her music compared to trash. (I am not the downvoter.)

Comment: @user105719 There is no definitive reading here. Sorry to tell you. The poster looks completely wasted. https://www.elle.com/culture/celebrities/a29689717/selena-gomez-taylor-swift-relationship-timeline/

Comment: @Lambie You're looking at a picture of Selena Gomez wheeling a trash dumpster out to the curb with the caption "Selena taking her music for a walk" and you think there's  no "definitive reading"? Sorry to tell you, but there is, and it has nothing to do with the link in your last comment. The punchline (i.e., the burn)  of the jibe is that Gomez' music is trash. By the way, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @user105719 You call the burn unit if you are hurt by being burned; you call the trash people to burn your trash. So the post is one big flop. You don't call the burn unit to burn your trash. I was trying to show that. So,she needs to clean up her post for other readings. As a flop, my reading is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's the function of a burn unit, which ZWhite33 says to call for Selena Gomez, who has been "burned" by atKelseHison's snarky comment comparing Gomez' music to trash. No one is burning trash. Selena Gomez is just wheeling a trash bin to the curb, an occasion for atKelseyHilson to say that that's the proper container for Gomez' music. As for being correct, your reading is a flop. Or you're just trolling me. I'm still not a downvoter.

Comment: @user105719 A disclaimer "Not a downvoter" should follow every comment under a downvoted answer. Abbreviation: "NAD". NAD. (I did upvote your comments, though.)

Comment: @EddieKal Thanks. I don't vote much period. Q or A, something has to strike me as special before I upvote. I don't see the point of downvoting questions, and if I think answers are wrong, I try to offer corrections, which I feel will be ill received if I also downvote the answers. I don't mind downvotes with explanations, but unexplained downotes can leave readers wondering what's wrong while giving the answerer no idea of what (if anything) needs fixing.

Comment: @user105719 I was joking about the abbreviation, seeing how much you'd stressed that you were NAD. Serious stuff: I don't spend much time on meta sites, but your suggestion that downvotes should be accompanied by some sort of explanation has been proposed several times on Meta.SE and maybe Meta.ELL too. I am for it, but it seems difficult to actually implement. I am more inclined to downvote a bad question than a bad answer. I only downvote an answer if I firmly believe it is wrong and no one has downvoted or voiced flak. A lot of questions, OTOH, are pure laziness and downvote-worthy IMHO.

Comment: @EddieKal I did enjoy the joking acronym and should have said so. Sorta serious stuff: my ideas about voting are strictly idiosyncratic and not a call to arms. To each his or her own. My view on downvotes without comments is distinctly a minority position. I'm sure laziness is behind some questions (especially the ones that are obviously homework), but I'm inclined to believe it's more often exasperation with the language.